# How to update user data after login in D8?

Tags: 8, users

I am trying to update user data after login in Drupal 8.3.x.
I have implemented the `hook_user_login` function as follows:

```
function custommodule_user_login($account) {
  // We could use $account->getAccountName() as username
  $user = user_load_by_name('myusername'); 
  $user->set('field_user_customfield', 'VALUE');
  $user->save();
}
```

The problem is that the modification is not being saved.
If I execute the modification from [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) PHP execution area, everything works fine and the change is reflected.

Note: I am using the [CAS](https://www.drupal.org/project/cas) module for login. Maybe that module is removing any change I do here?

What could be the issue? Can't we modify user data from user login hook in D8?

Comment: To check whether the CAS module is at fault, uinstall the module, clear the cache, and see if your code starts to work.

Comment: Did you confirm that your code is actually being run?

Comment: P.S. the `$account` parameter is the actual user object so the following might work: `$account->set('field_user_customfield', 'VALUE')->save();`

Comment: @Eyal The code runs and I believe the issue is related with the CAS module, which uses the ExternalAuth module. I may want to modify arbitrary users, no just the `$account` user.

Comment: If you are altering the current user, then you may need to use the provided account object - to make sure that change will be visible on this object as well.